# pgadmin/postgresql - port 5432 failed: timeout expired from Windws laptop

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, networking, pgadmin

Please would you help me diagnose my PostgreSQL 14 installation on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I cannot connect to it with pgAdmin 4 on my windows 11 laptop (192.168.1.67).

The full error is

`Unable to connect to server: connection to server at '192.168.1.145', port 5432 failed: timeout expired`

I have made the following file changes and checked status commands:-

`
[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBEeS.png)

[pg_hba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHlQV.png)

[pg_lsclusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAEOO.png)

[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM50y.png)

[ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThvXS.png)
`
Thanks

Lee

Comment: Looks like a networking issue.  The conf files can't matter, as you are never reaching the database in the first place.  It is probably a firewall issue.  The firewall at issue probably the one on the router between the two machines, not the one on the Linux machine itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `255.255.255.0` netmask in the pg_hba.conf file is wrong, you're specifying a single IP `192.168.1.67`, not all IPs in the `192.168.1.xxx` subnet.

The pg_hba entry should be `192.168.1.67 255.255.255.255` or `192.168.1.67/32`